# Как поставить libarchive на Ruby?

Tags: winrar, ruby, zip

> C:\Helper\genExt>gem install
> libarchive Temporarily enhancing PATH
> to include DevKit... Building native
> extensions.  This could take a
> while... ERROR:  Error installing
> libarchive:
>         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
> ```
>
> extconf.rb
>  ***extconf.rb failed***  Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
> probably lack of necessary libraries
> and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log
> file for more details.  You may need
> configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>         --with-opt-dir
>         --without-opt-dir
>         --with-opt-include
>         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>         --with-opt-lib
>         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>         --with-make-prog
>         --without-make-prog
>         --srcdir=.
>         --curdir
>         --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
> .1/gems/libarchive-0.1.2 for
> inspection. Results logged to
> C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/libarchiv e-0.1.2/ext/gem_make.out
>
> C:\Helper\genExt>

Как быть, что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно поставить [DevKits](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads).